# Equivalent to Jquery $(document).ajaxsend() in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using  `$( document ).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {})` to attach a generic function in my app whenever an ajax request is about to be send.

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/

What is the Vanilla / XMLHttpRequest equivalent to this event?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no equivalent.  The nearest would be to add `function();` in front of every XMLHttpRequest (or, more equivalently, `dispatchEvent`) - or wrap all your XMLHttpRequests in a function and put your function() in the wrapper (so there's only one place it's called)